# Plyr.io html5 quality selector not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html5-video, plyr.js

Quality selector not working when I call the  via jquery ajax.

HTML

```
<video style="background:black; border-radius:20px;"class="" id="player"  "> </video>
```

Ajax code

```
$.ajax({  
                url:"/retrieve/video.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{quality:quality,slig:slig,episode:episode,server:server},  
                success:function(data){  
                    
                    $("#loaders").hide();
            
                    $('#player').show();
                    $('#player').append(data);

                }                  
           });
```

Comment: have you checked for any errors in console? have you checked with manual values (that match what the ajax is returning) that it works as expected?

Comment: No errors at all, the ajax is working fine. It loaded the 3 <sources> with different resolution but the plyr.io can't change quality